# How can I limit the speed of the chasis fan on an Asus M5A78L-M LX PLUS?

Tags: cpu, motherboard, fan, cooling

I was working on an Asus M5A78L-M LX PLUS motherboard and I replaced the chassis fan with something a little bit quieter and with more CFMs.

However, once installed, it was *very* noisy and it was pushing a ton of air out. I thought that I must have accidentally plugged something in wrong and it was freaking out. I shut down the computer and everything was fine. I booted up again and looked at the fan speeds:

[image]

All the temperatures were within a reasonable range (the highest being the GPU). However, notice that the fan is running at almost 2500 RPM (the maximum speed)! I looked in BIOS all over and I could not find anything about the speed except Q-Fan (enabled by the way on "standard").

Note: the header/fan both are *not* PWM. However, my CPU fan is PWM, although it practically silent.

Comment: Until we get a standardized interface for fan speed control (sadly we'll never get one), forget the userspace fan control programs and look in the BIOS - auto fan speed control on ASUS boards is called Q-Fan if I remember right.

Comment: If you have no luck with the BIOS the best solution is to just cut the fan's connector and connect the two power wires in the +5V side of a molex connector - that'll make it run at half speed and it's usually enough for a case fan.